# input type file não carrega arquivo .CSV

Tags: php, csv

Olá, estou tentando pegar os dados de um arquivo .CSV com php, mas ao usar o input file para pegar o .csv não está carregando

codigo html

```
<form id="form" name="form"  action="add_analise.php" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="POST">

<input name="file" id="file" type="file"   />

<input type="submit"  value="Ver Analise" />  
    </form>
```

Codigo php

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
include("config/config.php");
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1",true);


// Abre o Arquvio no Modo r (para leitura)
$arquivo = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];
$arquivo = fopen ($arquivo, 'r');

// Lê o conteúdo do arquivo
while(!feof($arquivo)){
    // Pega os dados da linha
    $linha = fgets($arquivo, 1024);

    // Divide as Informações das celular para poder salvar
    $dados = explode(';', $linha);



echo $dados[0]."<br>"; 


    // Verifica se o Dados Não é o cabeçalho ou não esta em branco
    if($dados[0] != 'Date' && !empty($linha)){


        //mysql_query('INSERT INTO emails (nome, email) VALUES ("'.$dados[0].'", "'.$dados[1].'")');
    }
}

// Fecha arquivo aberto
fclose($arquivo);
```

o arquivo .CSV não está carregando de jeito nenhum, apos clicar no botão enviar, a pagina fica carregando, carregando e nada acontece, o arquivo tem apenas 10k/b

Answer (score 1):

O `$_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];` salva o arquivo na pasta `tmp` do sistema, esta pasta provavelmente não permite a leitura no momento do upload, talvez algo de permissão, deve ter ocorrido erros como:

> Warning: fopen(...): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Z:\web\inp\teste.php on line 9
>
> Warning: feof() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in Z:\web\inp\teste.php on line 12

O ideal é mover o seu CSV para uma pasta com permissões de leitura e também verificar se `fopen` conseguiu abrir o arquivo:

```
<?php
//Define o lugar que será salvo o arquivo com um nome aleatório
$arquivo = 'csv/' . uniqid(rand(), true) . '.csv';

if (empty($_FILES['file'])) {
    echo 'A requisição não veio por POST';
    exit;
} elseif ($_FILES['file']['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
    echo 'Erro ao fazer o upload', $_FILES['file']['error'];
    exit;
} elseif (!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $arquivo)) {
     echo 'Erro ao mover para a pasta';
     exit;
}

$handle = fopen ($arquivo, 'rb');

//Verifica se o arquivo pode ser lido
if (!$handle) {
    echo 'Falha ao ler o arquivo';
    exit;
}

// Lê o conteúdo do arquivo
while(!feof($handle)){
    // Pega os dados da linha
    $linha = fgets($handle, 1024);

    // Divide as Informações das celular para poder salvar
    $dados = explode(';', $linha);



     echo $dados[0]."<br>"; 


    // Verifica se o Dados Não é o cabeçalho ou não esta em branco
    if($dados[0] != 'Date' && !empty($linha)){


        //mysql_query('INSERT INTO emails (nome, email) VALUES ("'.$dados[0].'", "'.$dados[1].'")');
    }
}

// Fecha arquivo aberto
fclose($handle);

//Deleta o arquivo após usá-lo
unlink($arquivo);
```

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/58795/discussion-on-answer-by-guilherme-nascimento-input-type-file-nao-carrega-arquivo)